# Hover over sub-menu with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image: Actions Menu]
I have been tasked with automating the submission of a form (Company access only) and then exporting the results to excel. My code does click on the 'Actions' menu to activate the drop down list, but from there it does nothing. I need to hover over the Using Selenium, here is a snippet of the code, specifically for the menu I need to:
1. Hover over the "Open with Report Builder"
2. 'Down' arrow twice to 'Export'
3. 'Right' arrow over to the sub-sub-menu
4. 'Down' arrow 3x and 'click' on 'Excel'

```
elem4 = driver.find_element_by_id("m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01_t")
elem4.click()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elem4)
actions.perform()
elem4.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
elem4.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
elem4.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT)
elem4.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
elem4.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
elem4.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
elem4.click()
```

Here is the HTML associated with the 'Actions' Menu

```
<div id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01_t" class="ms-menubuttoninactivehover ms-displayBlock" title="Open Menu" onmouseover="MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)" hoveractive="ms-menubuttonactivehover ms-rteThemeBackColor-3-1 ms-displayBlock" hoverinactive="ms-menubuttoninactivehover ms-displayBlock" onclick="if (document.getElementById('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00').childNodes.length == 0) { MMU_CallbackPreMenuOpen('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00', 'm_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01', 'WebForm_DoCallback(\'m_sqlRsWebPart$RSWebPartToolbar$ctl00$RptControls$RSActionMenu$ctl01\',\'enabled\',MMU_CallbackHandler,\'__CALLBACKCONTEXT__\',MMU_CallbackErrHandler,true)', 60000, 'The request for menu items from the server has timed out.', event);  } CoreInvoke('MMU_Open',byid('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01'),event,true, null, 300); return false;" foa="MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01')" oncontextmenu="ClkElmt(this); return false;" style="white-space:nowrap"><a class="ms-menu-a" id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01" href="javascript:;" title="Open Menu" style="cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap;" onfocus="MMU_EcbLinkOnFocusBlur(byid('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00'), this, true);" onkeydown="MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01'), event);" onclick="if (document.getElementById('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00').childNodes.length == 0) { MMU_CallbackPreMenuOpen('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00', 'm_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01', 'WebForm_DoCallback(\'m_sqlRsWebPart$RSWebPartToolbar$ctl00$RptControls$RSActionMenu$ctl01\',\'enabled\',MMU_CallbackHandler,\'__CALLBACKCONTEXT__\',MMU_CallbackErrHandler,true)', 60000, 'The request for menu items from the server has timed out.', event);  } CoreInvoke('MMU_Open',byid('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl00'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01'),event,true, null, 300); return false;" oncontextmenu="ClkElmt(this); return false;" menutokenvalues="" serverclientid="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01" callbackinprogress="" menuitemsdisabled="" menuitemshidden="" menuitemschecked=""><span class="sqlrv-ActionMenuText sqlrv-ToolBarMenuCell">Actions</span><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" style="border:0px" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)."></a><img class="ms-viewselector-arrow" src="/_layouts/images/menudark.gif" alt="Open Menu"></div>
```

I believe this is the HTML for the 'Export' and 'Excel'

```
<ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_Export" type="submenu" text="Export" callbackitem="true"><ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_Export_Label" type="label" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_XML" type="option" onmenuclick="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;XML&quot;);" text="XML file with report data" callbackitem="true" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;XML&quot;);" text_original="XML file with report data" valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_CSV" type="option" onmenuclick="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;CSV&quot;);" text="CSV (comma delimited)" callbackitem="true" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;CSV&quot;);" text_original="CSV (comma delimited)" valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_PDF" type="option" onmenuclick="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;PDF&quot;);" text="PDF" callbackitem="true" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;PDF&quot;);" text_original="PDF" valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_EXCELOPENXML" type="option" onmenuclick="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;EXCELOPENXML&quot;);" text="Excel" callbackitem="true" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;EXCELOPENXML&quot;);" text_original="Excel" valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_IMAGE" type="option" onmenuclick="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;IMAGE&quot;);" text="TIFF file" callbackitem="true" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;IMAGE&quot;);" text_original="TIFF file" valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_WORDOPENXML" type="option" onmenuclick="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;WORDOPENXML&quot;);" text="Word" callbackitem="true" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;WORDOPENXML&quot;);" text_original="Word" valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
<ie:menuitem id="m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_MHTML" type="option" onmenuclick="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;MHTML&quot;);" text="MHTML (web archive)" callbackitem="true" menugroupid="2147483647" enabled="true" checked="false" onmenuclick_original="$find(&quot;m_sqlRsWebPart_ctl00_ReportViewer&quot;).exportReport(&quot;MHTML&quot;);" text_original="MHTML (web archive)" valorig="
"></ie:menuitem>
</ie:menuitem>
```

Comment: Do you have a possibility to get HTML for `Export` and `Excel`?

Comment: I updated the question - the 'Inspect' option is not available when I right-click on the sub-menu so I just had to assume that this HTML is associated with the 'Export' option.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code-

```
actions_menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@alt='Open Menu']").click()
export = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@text='Export']")
excel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@text='Excel']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(export).click(excel).perform()
```

Comment: Still no luck - but thank you for the response. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong section of HTML code - the "Export" menu must be hidden, meaning I can't right-click on it and choose "Inspect" from Chrome - right-clicking on it does nothing